# What data does Layer 2 Rollups commit to Layer 1?

Tags: scalability, rollups, zero-knowledge

Trying to understand what happens with rollups and other scaling solutions. What is confusing to me is that when reading about rollups I see that what gets updated is the Merkle root of the state of the rollup and I guess this is the part that covers **data availability** with rollups. So when looking at this picture below I am not sure what gets updated on smart contract with the part where it says **proofs** and what proofs then do rollups send and what validiums or voltions?

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the lazy comment. I recommend reading  Georgios Konstantopoulos' [(Almost) Everything you need to know about Optimistic Rollup](https://research.paradigm.xyz/rollups).

Comment: A suggestion is to edit the title to "What data does Layer 2 ZK Rollups commit to Layer 1?"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer here, this guy made nice explanation what happens with rollups
https://twitter.com/bkiepuszewski/status/1471116288261038088

Comment: You asked about validiums and volitions (zk rollups) which this tweet is totally not about... This tweet is about optimistic rollups which are different from zk rollups.

Comment: you suggested to do change title to ZK 2 years ago which I did for some reason, now you are against that :)

I changed it to be without ZK as that is proper.

Comment: Your question and diagram is still about validiums and volitions (zk rollups) and I am not against that. Changing the title to remove ZK does not change what your question is about. What does not make sense is asking about zk rollups and posting an answer about optimistic rollups.