# what data of zk rollup blockchain are sent to l1?

Tags: zksnark, rollups, l2

I am not clear about how data flow from l2 to l1 in zk rollups. does someone knows what data of l2 are sended to l1?

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/116817/119701). It's a good explanation for what you need.